# Adding server click to dynamic asp button in aspnet gridview header

Tags: c#, gridview, dopostback

I have to add a button in the gridview header spanning two columns.  I do this in the code behind:

```
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            GridView HeaderGrid = (GridView)sender;
            GridViewRow HeaderGridRow =
            new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header,
            DataControlRowState.Insert);  
            TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell(); 
            HeaderCell.Text = "Name of Person";
            HeaderCell.Font.Bold = true;
            HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 1;
            HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
            HeaderCell = new TableCell();

            Button btnHeader = new Button();
            btnHeader.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
            btnHeader.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnsubmitentry_Click);
            btnHeader.Text = "Add New Task";
            btnHeader.CommandName = "AddNewTask";
            //  OnClick="btnsubmitentry_Click"
            btnHeader.CssClass = "btn btn-lg btn-default";
            btnHeader.OnClientClick = "AddNewTask();";
            HeaderCell.Controls.Add(btnHeader);
            HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 2;
            HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

            grdViewSummary.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderGridRow);
        }
```

This generates a nice button, however I need help how to invoke the server side button click event.

```
<input type="button" name="grdViewSummary$ctl01$ctl00" value="Add New Task" onclick="AddNewTask();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;grdViewSummary$ctl01$ctl00&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))" class="btn btn-lg btn-default"   />
```

As you can see, I passed in a onClientClick to a javascript function that has the postback code, but the event is not fired.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AddNewTask() {
        alert();
        __doPostBack('btnsubmitentry_Click','')
    }
</script>
```

I also have tried passing in the eventhandler and CommandName. But none of these are shown in the view source of the button in question. 
I will be okay with any approach; calling postback on javascript function or, calling the server side click routine directly or, invokes the commandname grdiview function.

Comment: in which event are you creating this control?  Event handlers cannot be added to dynamic controls during a postback event such as `RowDataBound`

Comment: that rules out then event handler approach as this dyanmic control was being created in gridview_rowcreated routine.  The reason to do so, is because this button control would take up two column span space.

Comment: well you can build the control into the gridview template and then just alter the span in row created.

Comment: What do you mean? How do I insert a control in HeaderText = "" area of the templatefield.

Comment: you don't - you add it to the <HeaderTemplate> of the <TemplateField> and style the contol as normal and you can style the <HeaderTemplate> in the <HeaderStyle /> tag of the <TemplateField>.  I'll post an example

Comment: C# is case sensitive - is that how your event definition is written? btnsubmitentry_Click (I don't see the definition in your sample)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template fields also contain Header and Footer Template zones that can hold controls

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name Of Person" SortExpression="parent">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnHeader" runat="server" 
             OnClientClick="AddNewTask()"     <-- this is not needed see update below
             CommandName="AddNewTask"
             CssClass="btn btn-lg btn-default"
             Text="Add New Task" 
             UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="true" />
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind(...)%>' ></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind(...)%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Update**

Now because the button is in the header it's auto wired to the gridview and on click will fire a RowCommand that can be caught in the GridView RowCommand Event.  Process the CommandName and call what functions you need in the code behind

Comment: Sometimes we forget the basics - isn't it. Will try this. RowCommand will be excellent approach.

Comment: Plugged in and the click of button didnt fire anything.  The view source gives me  `<th scope="col">
                                <input type="button" name="grdViewSummary$ctl01$btnHeader" value="Add New Task" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;grdViewSummary$ctl01$btnHeader&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))" id="grdViewSummary_btnHeader" class="btn btn-default" />
                            </th>`

Comment: Ain't that the truth brother :) Keep in mind that a Gridview isn't really designed for Insert operations. Consider using a FormView or DetailsView for the insert.

Comment: try enabling submit behavior

Comment: i just created a dummy gridview with a default button in the header - I do get a rowcommand event that I can break on, and just tried again without submit behavior, works both ways. Also make sure OnClientClick event is cleared

Comment: I had validation group going, hence had to include CausesValidation set to false as well.  And at the row created, I have altered the span as such      `         
      protected void grdViewSummary_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[4].ColumnSpan = 2;
            }   `